# How to store arrays in queues?

Tags: java, c++

I was coding some piece of code and I came up with an Issue ,
it is how to insert arrays in Queue ?
let me give explain you by an example....

```
array1[9]={1,3,4,2,1,2,3,4,1}
array2[9]={2,3,4,2,4,2,2,2,3}

//create a queue (I don't know how to declare a queue for this issue)...

queue.push(array1);
queue.push(array2);
//##############################
//when I print queue.front()...
//########################
printf("%d",queue.front());
```

The above snippet should print every element of array1 !! How it can be done ??

Comment: I think you should either `c` or `c++` for this question. Both are quite different languages.

Comment: Have a look at a queue tutorial: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57487-stl-queues/

Comment: Should you not be using `queue< vector<int> >`?

Comment: Or perhaps a std::queue< std::array<int, 9> >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy if you use `std::array` instead of C-style arrays.

```
std::array<int, 9> array1 = { 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 };
std::array<int, 9> array2 = { 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3 };

std::queue<std::array<int, 9>> queue;

queue.push(array1);
queue.push(array2);

for (auto i : queue.front()) {
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph !! ,But is it same if I want to pop the front array1? If I write Queue.pop() it should remove array1 from the queue !! Is it same as the above ??

Comment: @BharathM No `pop()` removes the element, but `front()` doesn't. `front()` only returns a reference to the element.

Answer (score 0):

This is too simple answer for this question. if you need dynamic array size, just search it exactly in your favorite search engine :-)

```
int array1[9]={1,3,4,2,1,2,3,4,1};
int array2[9]={2,3,4,2,4,2,2,2,3};
std::vector<int> a1(9);
std::vector<int> a2(9);
for(int i =0; i< 9;i++){        
    a1[i]=array1[i];
    a2[i]=array2[i];// <= a2[i] should take values from array2[i]
}
std::queue<std::vector<int>> queue;    
queue.push(a1);
queue.push(a2);
//std::cout<<queue.size()<<std::endl;
std::vector<int> temp(9);
int size =queue.size();
for(int i =0; i< size;i++){        
    temp=queue.front();
    std::cout<<"Array["<<i<<"]: ";
    for(int j =0; j< temp.size();j++)
        std::cout<<temp[j]<<",";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    queue.pop();
}
```